# Convert money data type to a number in postgres

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, currency

I'd like to convert a value of money data type to integer so that I perform multiplication operation.

I am doing this since money * money operation is not supported error is observed when I try them multiplying with out converting

Comment: That's nice. When you run into a specific problem, you can try posting here in SO. Unfortunately, SO is not a free coding service. And to accomplish your goal, you will need to have rather significant skills in in both database engines (and like the different features supported by various editions and versions). I suggest you start by simply searching the internet using "migrate sql server postgres" if you need direction.

Comment: You [shouldn't be using](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) `money` to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Try it `your_money_field::numeric::int`

Example:

```
SELECT cost 
FROM "Product" 
WHERE cost::numeric::int > 100
```